# Remove existing effect before recalling a custom function

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario like i have made a function to display data grid on page and i call it on document ready event. Now i have also given links to update the record and once the record updated i would like to recall the function so that it will show updated results. The problem is that when i update the record and recall my function to show results it actually adds new  after the existing table. What i want is to recall latest record not add new row. So basically i want to know how can i uncall/unset someting like that a function and then recall it.

below is how i m calling.

```
 //Update customers
    $("#form").on('click', "#update", function() {
        var data = $.param($("#form").serializeArray());
        event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "crudcustomers.php",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(msg) {
                            $("#message").attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
                            $("#message").html(msg);
                            // Rebind datagrid after record added.
                            getRecords();
                        }
                    });
    });
```

So if  you see i rebind the datagrid with getRecords(); function. I need to remove the complete datagrid that was called on document.ready and then recall it in above function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.remove()` on table's `tr`

```
$('table').find('tbody tr').remove();
```

**jsfiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/Pg2FD/

Comment: will it remvoe all trs ?

Comment: Got it thanks :) but isn't there any way that we can uncall and recall function ?

Comment: What do you mean by "uncall" ?